# Inner join no entityframework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Eu preciso fazer um inner join no entity frameworkm no banco, eu consigo fazer normalmente desta forma:

```
select * from Produtos inner join ProdutosEmpresas on ProdutoID = Produtos.Id
```

Porém no entity framework eu não consigo, ele não aparece a tabela para fazer o include.

Aqui é como está atualmente:

```
var produtos = db.Produtos.OrderBy(a => a.Codigo).Where(a => a.ControleEstoque == true).ToList();
```

Preciso fazer o inner join da tabela Produtos com a tabela ProdutosEmpresas. Tentei fazer com `Include`, porém ele não aparece a tabela para colocar. Não entendi o porque.

`ProdutosEmpresas`

```
 public class ProdutosEmpresas
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Empresa EmpresaProduto { get; set; }
    public int EmpresaID { get; set; }
    public Produto ProdutoEmpresa { get; set; }
    public int ProdutoID { get; set; }
    public int Qtd { get; set; }
    public decimal PrecoCusto { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal PrecoVenda { get; set; }
}
```

`Produtos`

```
 public class Produto
{

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Codigo { get; set; }

    [StringLength(120)]
    public string nome { get; set; }
    public int QtdAtual { get; set; }
    public int QtdMinima { get; set; }
    public int QtdMaxima { get; set; }

    public decimal PrecoCusto { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal PrecoVenda { get; set; }
    public decimal CustoMedio { get; set; }

    public float ICMS { get; set; }

    public float ISS { get; set; }

    public float IPI { get; set; }
    public float Margem { get; set; }
    public float Comissao { get; set; }
    public int CategoriaID { get; set; }
    public Categoria Categoria { get; set; }
    //public int EmpresaID { get; set; }
    //public Empresa Empresa { get; set; }

    [StringLength(500)]
    public string observacao { get; set; }
    [StringLength(8)]
    public string NCM { get; set; }

    public bool ControleEstoque { get; set; }
    public byte[] Foto { get; set; }

    public bool TipoProduto { get; set; }
    public bool TipoSoftware { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Consegue postar o código das suas entidades Produtos e ProdutosEmpresas? Se você tiver feito o relacionamento entre elas talvez você nem precise do include.

Comment: @GeorgeWurthmann atualizei a pergunta com Produtos e ProdutosEmpresas.

Comment: Faltou a propriedade de referência em Produto de ProdutosEmpresa. 
http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entity-relationships.aspx

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/ef/ef6/fundamentals/relationships

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode (ou até deve) especificar o relacionamento entre as entidades.

Você pode fazer isso adicionando a seguinte linha no ProdutosEmpresas:

```
[ForeignKey("Id")]
public Produtos Produtos { get; set; }
```

Ficaria assim:

```
public class ProdutosEmpresas
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Empresa EmpresaProduto { get; set; }
    public int EmpresaID { get; set; }
    public Produto ProdutoEmpresa { get; set; }
    public int ProdutoID { get; set; }
    public int Qtd { get; set; }
    public decimal PrecoCusto { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal PrecoVenda { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public Produtos Produtos { get; set; }
}
```

E na entidade Produto adicione a linha:

```
public virtual ICollection<ProdutosEmpresas> { get; set; }
```

Fazendo isso a Propriedade `Produtos` do `ProdutosEmpresas` seria carregado pelo **Lazy Loading**.

Comment: Deu certinho, obrigado, Era desta forma que eu queria mesmo.

Answer (score 3):

O EF possui um método chamado `Join`.

[Veja os docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/method-based-query-syntax-examples-join-operators#join)

O seu código ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
ObjectSet<Produto> produtos = db.Produto;
ObjectSet<SProdutosEmpresas> produtosEmpresas = db.ProdutosEmpresas;

var resultado = produtos
    .Join(produtosEmpresas, pe => pe.ProdutoID, (p, pe) => new { Produto = p, ProdutoEmpresa = pe })
    .Where(x => x.Produto.ControleEstoque)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Produto.Codigo)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Não deu certo, ele não aceitou esta parte `pe.ProdutoID`, então fiz assim: `var resultado = db.Produtos
    .Join(db.ProdutosEmpresas, pe => pe.Id, (p, pe) => new { Produto = p, ProdutoEmpresa = pe })
    .Where(x => x.Produto.ControleEstoque == true)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Produto.Codigo)
    .ToList();` porém também não deu certo, ele dá o seguinte erro:   Gravidade Código Descrição Projeto Arquivo Linha Estado de Supressão
Erro CS1501 Nenhuma sobrecarga para o método "Join" leva 3 argumentos

Comment: você está usando qual versão do Entity Framework?

Comment: Versão 2.1.1 EntityFrameworkCore.